# Search Excel Worksheet for text highlighted in Outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, find

Everyday I get emails with project numbers on them. I usually highlight and copy the project number from the email, click on my excel spreadsheet (WI_Design_Tracker), `ctrl + F` (to find) and paste the project number into the find field, then `Find Next`.  I'm trying to create a macro that will shorten the process since I do it a hundred times a day.  I found a macro that does the opposite (finds a highlighted number in Excel and searches through Outlook to find the email. I tried to amend it to fit my purposes but it's above my skill level.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here's the code I'm trying to convert to search my Excel worksheet for the project number I have highlighted on an Outlook email.

```
'Code:
Option Explicit

Public Sub Search_Outlook_Emails()

    Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim outNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim outStartFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim foundEmail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set outApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set outNs = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    'Start at Inbox's parent folder
    Set outStartFolder = outNs.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.olFolderInbox).Parent

    'Or start at folder selected by user
    'Set outStartFolder = outNs.PickFolder


    If Not outStartFolder Is Nothing Then

        Set foundEmail = Find_Email_In_Folder(outStartFolder, ActiveCell.Value)

        If Not foundEmail Is Nothing Then

            If MsgBox("Email subject: " & foundEmail.Subject & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                      "Folder: " & foundEmail.Parent.FolderPath & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                      "Open the email?", vbYesNo, "'" & ActiveCell.Value & "' found") = vbYes Then

                foundEmail.Display

            End If

        Else

            MsgBox "", vbOKOnly, "'" & ActiveCell.Value & "' not found"

        End If

    End If

End Sub

Private Function Find_Email_In_Folder(outFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, findText As String) As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim outItem As Object
    Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim outSubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim i As Long

    Debug.Print outFolder.FolderPath

    Set Find_Email_In_Folder = Nothing

    'Search emails in this folder

    i = 1
    While i <= outFolder.Items.Count And Find_Email_In_Folder Is Nothing

        Set outItem = outFolder.Items(i)

        If outItem.Class = Outlook.OlObjectClass.olMail Then

            'Does the findText occur in this email's body text?

            Set outMail = outItem
            If InStr(1, outMail.Body, findText, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then Set Find_Email_In_Folder = outMail

        End If

        i = i + 1

    Wend

    DoEvents

    'If not found, search emails in subfolders

    i = 1
    While i <= outFolder.Folders.Count And Find_Email_In_Folder Is Nothing

        Set outSubFolder = outFolder.Folders(i)

        'Only check mail item folders

        If outSubFolder.DefaultItemType = Outlook.olMailItem Then Set Find_Email_In_Folder = Find_Email_In_Folder(outSubFolder, findText)

        i = i + 1

    Wend

End Function
```

Comment: Your posted code isn't really relevant here: if anything it may lead people to wonder why - if you have existing code like this - you can't make a start at what you describe.  Here's a good place for you to start - http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?52985-VBA-get-selected-text-from-Outlook-email-body-and-use-in-Excel

Comment: You may wanna post sample data of you spreadsheet and your email

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link Tim. That was much simpler.  I'd had seen that code before but wasn't able to make it work so I tried again.  Here's what I ended up with.  It could still use some tweaking and error handling, but this is what's working for now:

```
Sub FindOutlookValue()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim olInsp As Object
Dim WdDoc As Object
Dim strText As String

On Error Resume Next

'Get Outlook if it's running
Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

With OutMail
    Set olInsp = .GetInspector
    Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
    strText = WdDoc.Application.Selection.Range.Text
End With

'Find strText in Excel
Dim cl As Range
With Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Cells
    Set cl = .Find(strText, After:=.Range(A1), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not cl Is Nothing Then
       cl.Select
    End If
End With

End Sub
```